# How do I read line by line and only return lines that have a number greater than 0.0

Tags: javascript, php

I want to read lines inserted into a textarea and return the lines that have values greater than 0.0 -  This is an example of the lines that I'm inputting into the textarea:

```
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
```

Those would be examples of what the lines would have
the value that should be sent back is since the last numbers are grater than 0.0

```
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
```

code for each line

```
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    //read line
}
```

and, also tried with Javascript

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //code here using lines[i] which will give each line but how do I look
    //for the last numbers to make sure that the numbers are grater than 0.0
}
```

Comment: Use regular expressions and replace function

Comment: In JS you only need one line of code: `$("textarea").val().split("\n").filter(line => Number(line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/)[0]) > 0).join("\n")`. Something like this?

Comment: @Xufox i've tried this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=FgsNIxyOfP)

Comment: @learningbyexample PHP runs on the server, not in the browser. I’m not sure what you’re trying to show me with your JSFiddle. Also, you need to do something with the result. That line of code returns the filtered lines, but you need to assign them somewhere or use them somehow.

Comment: yeah sorry @Xufox copied straight from sublime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter as suggested by Xufox (check for null, because it will cause an error "Cannot read property '0' of null")

```js
function getLines()
{
  return $("textarea").val().split("\n").filter(line => line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/) != null && Number(line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/)[0]) > 0);
}
      
$(document).ready(
  function(){
     $('#printlogs').html(getLines().join('<br>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:120px">
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
</textarea>

<h4>Error Log</h4>
<printlogs id="printlogs"></printlogs>
```

Comment: The downvote was for your answer containing only a vague sentence. _Now_ you’ve edited a snippet into it. Anyway, why not use `filter` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: yeah filter is minimal code but foreach is more efficient I mean faster

Comment: Is it? `filter` is the right tool here, and it’s built-in, too, so any speed difference is negligible and will vary strongly over time and with different browsers.

Comment: Hey @AnanthakrishnanBaji thanks for your answer, just that when I tried to run it, it gives me this in the javascript part
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at getLines (javascript.js:4)
    at javascript.js:13**

Comment: This error occurs when  $('textarea') is undefined, either your html doest have a textarea, or you have used a wrong selector

Comment: @AnanthakrishnanBaji I forgot the $(document).ready
is there a way to output it in a div rather than in console.log?

Comment: I tried **<printlogs id="printlogs"></printlogs>**  using **$('#printlogs').text(getLines().join('<br>'));** but the line break is not working

Comment: $('#your_div').html(getLines().join('<br>'))

Comment: Replace text() with html()

Answer (score 3):

In javascript, you can start with a function that will filter your lines

```
var endsAboveZero = function(line) {
    var words = lines.split(/\s/);
    var last = words[words.length - 1];
    return parseFloat(last) > 0;
};
```

Then you can filter your lines based on this. It's a one liner if you can use `Array.filter`:

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var goodLines = lines.filter(endsAboveZero);
```

or, with a for-loop:

```
var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
var goodLines = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (endsAboveZero(lines[i])) {
        goodLines.push(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

You may want to add some error checking in case of odd inputs in your textarea.